# Gibbs free energy in chemical reaction

Tags: thermodynamics, free-energy

I know this kind of question has been asked many times but I think this is a bit different.

We have $G = H - TS$. Here I am talking about chemical reactions at constant pressure and temperature. We can write $\Delta G = Q - Q_\mathrm{rev} = \Delta H - T \Delta S$.

For an irreversible chemical reaction, for example an exothermic one, if $q = -10~\mathrm{kJ~mol^{-1}}$ (exothermic), then $Q_\mathrm{rev}$ could be $-9$, $-8$, $-7$, etc.  The difference $(Q – Q_\mathrm{rev})$ would be negative ($-1$, $-2$, $-3$, etc.).  This represents the portion of $Q$ that can be converted into non-PV work.  The remainder of the heat is dispersed into the surrounding and is wasted. Right?

So here $Q$ as absolute value is more than $Q_\mathrm{rev}$, so we have more heat generated than a reversible chemical reaction that can be used as work ($Q = 8~\mathrm{kJ~mol^{-1}}$ and $Q_\mathrm{rev} = 2~\mathrm{kJ~mol^{-1}}$). So why is it said that a reversible reaction produces more useful heat? Again, I am talking about chemical reaction and not mechanical process.

Comment: Can you cite a reference for the equation $\Delta G = Q - Q_\mathrm{rev} $?

Comment: https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiI2K7HzJ_JAhXL1hoKHTkmANUQFggiMAE&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.usna.edu%2FUsers%2Fchemistry%2Fmorse%2F_files%2Fdocuments%2FSC112-Chapter18%2Foptional18.doc&usg=AFQjCNHwJqyIG_IR8g7YSAphCqQxhqFYQQ&sig2=8n2Uv6uPvkD3kkVBsSlSzw&bvm=bv.108194040,d.d2s

Actually I found it on google and it is from www.usna.edu (a doc file). It is logical that ΔG=Q−Qrev since ΔS = Qrev/T

Comment: Can you explain why you find it logical, given that $\Delta G$ and $\Delta S$ are functions of state, while Q is not a function of state?  Can you also provide the exact web site address?

Comment: Hello, it is a doc file inside the website which is downloaded automatically when you press on the link. The original website is www.usna.edu (US navy academy)

Comment: You can search it on google type: optional18 + usna.edu

Comment: In my judgement, the development in the usna document that led to the relationship  you cited is fallacious at many levels.  This is not a peer reviewed document, and I don't think you can find this equation in any peer reviewed literature.  I invite you to search the peer reviewed  literature to see if you can.